# how to sort a merged object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have 2 objects that i use merge on them like below :

```
$data = $city->merge($accommodation);
        return AccCitySearchResource::collection($data);
```

and in my resource

```
 return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'english_name' => $this->english_name,
            'accommodation_type_id' =>$this->accommodation_type_id,
            'grade_stars' =>$this->grade_stars,
            'hits' =>$this->hits,
            'accommodation_count' => $this->accommodation_count,
        ];
```

now all i want is that my `$data` first shows all cities and then shows all accommodations but now it shows all together is there any way to sort them ??

## EDIT

### This is what i get now

```
{
id: 5,
name: "hotel",
accommodation_type_id: 1,
grade_stars: 4,
hits: 22,
accommodation_count: null
},
{
id: 7,
name: "city",
accommodation_type_id: null,
grade_stars: null,
hits: null,
accommodation_count: 0
},
{
id: 10,
name: "hotel",
accommodation_type_id: 1,
grade_stars: 2,
hits: 0,
accommodation_count: null
},
```

### And this is what i want

```
{
id: 5,
name: "hotel",
accommodation_type_id: 1,
grade_stars: 4,
hits: 22,
accommodation_count: null
},
{
id: 10,
name: "hotel",
accommodation_type_id: 1,
grade_stars: 2,
hits: 0,
accommodation_count: null
},
{
id: 7,
name: "city",
accommodation_type_id: null,
grade_stars: null,
hits: null,
accommodation_count: 0
},
```

just to mention as you see all hotels comes first and then all cities come .

Comment: Did you tried `sortBy`? for example `$data->sortBy('name');`

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) is to create your own resource collection if you need to customise the default behavior:

```
php artisan make:resource AccCitySearchCollection
```

Then you can customise your collection:

```
class AccCitySearchCollection{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->sortBy('name')
        ];
    }
}
```

You can then return a collection instance:

```
$data = $city->merge($accommodation);
return new AccCitySearchCollection($data);
```

Comment: `'data' => $this->collection->sortBy('name')` This line will sort by name and because `c` comes before `h` cities will come before hotels

Comment: aaa i dont want to sort by name i merge 2 collections i want first collection items comes first then next one

Comment: @Farshad it's strange that you are not getting things in the order the collection is created. I may have misunderstood your question due to you saying *any way to sort them*. I would  try `$city->toBase()->values()->merge($accommodation->toBase()->values())` just to eliminate the possibilty there's some weird database collection behaviour getting in the way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sortBy` Collection method

Created Resource Collection for model.
Then in toArray method write:

```php
/**
 * Transform the resource collection into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection->sortByDesc(function($d){
            return (int) ($d['name'] == 'hotel');
        }),
    ];
}
```

This will sort your data as you want.
Hope this answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ... But if you are getting your data from a database , maybe you could join and order the query instead..

```
$data = $city->merge($accommodation)->sortByDesc('some field of first object here');
```